# How Do I Search and Replace Twice

Tags: php, replace

I developed a template system that search for tags like {tag} and dynamically replace them with content inside template file when loaded.

What im trying to do is make a tag like this `{download='text for button'}`

Below is how all my tags begin

```
//Download button
$download = '<a class="button">Download</a>';
$search = "{download}";
if (contains($string,$search))
    $string=str_ireplace($search,$download,$string);
```

So while {download} returns `<a class="button">Download</a>` this {download='button text'} should return `<a class="button">button text</a>`

Comment: Idea is great, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Its was easy to setup, users are allowed to basically create their own template using html/css but certain things are made the same using these tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one?

```
<?php

  $str = '{download} button {download="hello"} {download=\'hey\'} assa {download="asa"}';

  $str = str_replace('{download}', '{download="Download"}', $str);

  $str = preg_replace(
        '/\{download(\=\"(.*)\"|\=\'(.*)\'|)\}/siU',
        '<a href="#" class="button">$2</a>',
        $str);

  echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: I've put a fully working example, so just replace $str with the string you want to "search in".

Comment: Im confused on  $str = str_replace('{download}', '{download="Download"}', $str); whats it for?

Comment: Mr Johnson, if you replace this line, the button will never have a default text. This is to replace any {download} code with {download="Download"} before doing any core work.

Comment: I don't get your point, why do you want to use your code? I've rewritten yours in a way that it matches the requirements of your question. Can you elaborate more on what you are looking for?

Comment: My code is basically how the template system, it loads template file which is $string, then it should search for {download} and replace it i dont know how i can plug in your code to do that

Comment: Well, in your code, there is "$download" just replace it with "$string" and it should work. By the way, you have lots of unuseful code. Check this: http://pastebin.com/dS37CPeX

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/{download='(.*?)'}/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    $string = str_replace("{download='" . $val[1] . "'}", "<a class=\"button\">" . $val[1] . "</a>",  $string);
}
```

This should work.

Example:
http://3v4l.org/cl1aI

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this one - as ex3v said - seems to be a little bit like a 'reinventing the wheel' problem for me too, but I kinda liked it, so I played around a little bit, but without regex, as I wanted it to be a more generic solution, that enables custom attributes (but without whitespaces as attribute value). So it ended up like this:

```
<?php

function use_template($search,$replace,$string, $options=array()) {

    $searchdata = explode(" ", $search); //{download, text='Fancy'}
    $template = substr($searchdata[0],1); // download


    for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($searchdata);$i++) {
        $attribute = explode("=", $searchdata[$i]); //$attribute[0] = "text"; $attribute[1] = "'Fancy'}"
        if (endsWith($attribute[1],'}')) {
            $options[$attribute[0]] = substr($attribute[1], 0, -1);
        } else {
            $options[$attribute[0]] = $attribute[1];
        }
    }

    $a = str_ireplace("{".$template."}",$replace,$string); // Hello, this is my {<a class="button">[text]</a>} button
    foreach($options as $to_replace => $newval) {
        $a = str_ireplace("[".$to_replace."]", $newval, $a); // Hello, this is my Fancy button
    }
    return $a;
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === "" || substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}

$download = '<a class="button" style="background-color: [color];">[text]</a>';
$search = "{download text='Fancy' color=red}";
$string = "Hello, this is my {download} button!";
$options = array("text" => "Download", "color" => "#000000");


$string= use_template($search,$download,$string,$options);
echo $string;
?>
```